# How to pass a map<String,Map<String,Integer>> with application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when I have in application.properties:

```
config.map-of-map.Key1.Key2=111
```

this can not be match to variable:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapOfMap;
```

what is part of class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public MyClass getMyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

when I want to read data from this map I read String instead of Integer and get Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

is there some way how to force it to Integer ?

Comment: How did you try to read the data? Can you please show the code?

Comment: it is spring-boot application which reads data from this file by default. It is spring-boot feature

Comment: How have you set it up? Can you show the feature configuration? There is a type mismatch, obviously... From your property sample, I can only imagine `111` being parsed as `String` and then it is tried to be put into a `Map<String, Integer>` as value.

Comment: The way properties stores data initially is all strings, so you are trying to cast the values of Map<String, String> to Map<String, Integer>, you'll have to manually convert them by using Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why there is so negative votes for this question.
But all I need to do is just upgrade spring boot version.

I was using version  2.1.1.RELEASE 
but with version 2.2.1.RELEASE it can parse also Integer in map. Then I just follow this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-booT/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding) for nested map mapping

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the below pattern to support

`Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>` format in

`application.properties` file

```
personsInfo={'mahesh':{'age', 25}}
```